# How to create nested dictionary from XML using python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, xml-parsing

I am reading an XML file and take part of it and write it to YAML file.
For example, in this xml file,

```
<project>


  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <assignedNode>python</assignedNode>
  <canRoam>false</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
      <spec>H * * * *</spec>
    </hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
```

I want to read only the disabled value and the spec value and write it to a YAML file like this:
Expected output:

```
disabled: 'false'
name: Cancellation_CMT_Tickets
triggers:
  hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger:
    spec: H * * * *
```

Only when my resultant dictionary is in this format

```
d = {"trigger":{"hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger": {"spec": "H * * * *"}}}
```

I can dump that into yaml file with the above format. MY current code looks like this, search key is passed as runtime arguments

```
import os, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import yaml,sys
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

d = {}
def xmpparse(root,searchkey):
    for child in root:
        if child.tag == searchkey:
            d[child.tag]=child.text
        elif len(child):
           xmpparse(child,searchkey)
for i in sys.argv:
    xmpparse(root,i)

print(yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=False))
```

Current output:

```
disabled: 'false'
spec: H * * * *
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know much (or anything...) about YAML, but I can get your dictionary to its proper format (using the lxml library), if that helps.

Comment: I want to have a nested dictionary for only the entries I need to grab from the XML. Can you help me with that? While doing the recursive operation, it should start putting the values in nested dictionary

Comment: Let me know if the answer below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should take care of the nested dictionary problem, at least; it's based on various answers on SO on how to form nested dictionaries (and there may be other methods):

```
    import lxml.html as LH

    class NestedDict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
              self[key] = NestedDict()
              return self[key]

    data =     [your xml above]

    doc = LH.fromstring(data)

    for i in doc:
           if i.tag == 'triggers':
                for child in i.getchildren():
                    d = NestedDict()
                    d[i.tag][child.tag][child[0].tag] = i.text_content().strip()

    print(d)
```

Output:

> {'triggers': {'hudson.triggers.timertrigger': {'spec': 'H * * * *'}}}

Comment: I forgot to mention something, my code should work in such a way that, it can go any depth for the searchKey passed as runtime arguments. It looks like your solution can just work for this XML file. I didn't try that yet though. But d[i.tag][child.tag][child[0].tag] here you are just making entry with 3 keys